No change happen in actual DataFrame. Also I am using "inplace"
I have a dataframe in that dataframe I wont to fill NaN value with mean present in Purchase column according to city name. City name is like A, B and C.
When I Execute this query :
data[data["City_Category"] == "A"]["Purchase"].fillna(data.groupby("City_Category")["Purchase"].mean()[0],inplace=True)

I got this :
C:\Users\aniru\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10800\164244184.py:1: FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`
  data[data["City_Category"] == "A"]["Purchase"].fillna(data.groupby("City_Category")["Purchase"].mean()[0])
0          8370.000000
1         15200.000000
2          1422.000000
3          1057.000000
5         15227.000000
              ...     
233547     8911.939216
233552     8911.939216
233571     8911.939216
233587     8911.939216
233590     8911.939216

I want to mean of purchase value according to city name

You're filling a copy, not the original dataframe.

but how can i make changes in my Purchase column..

The duplicate explains multiple techniques for changing the actual column. Try one of those, if you still have problems, ask another question.
